# clickable overlay in ansi-term

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

I am the author of the [julia-repl](https://melpa.org/#/julia-repl) package, which runs an inferior Julia REPL inside [ansi-term](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm). A full terminal is necessary because of color and terminal interactions. I need some help extending this to make error locations "clickable".

Julia error messages look like this:

```
julia> Foo.foo()
ERROR: DomainError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo() at /tmp/Foo.jl:2
```

I would like to make the `/tmp/Foo.jl:2` "clickable", so that a mouse click takes the user to line `2` of `/tmp/Foo.jl`.

I started reading [the relevant section of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) but need some help implementing this. In particular,

1. what's the best way to find these snippets of text with a regex?
2. how to run this each time the buffer changes?
3. can I run this on only the new output?
4. how to specify a particular line of a file as a target?

I am happy to do some reading and study existing examples, but don't know where to start. A minimal example would help a lot.

Comment: I recommend looking at the sources of modes that do this, such as [grep.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/grep.el).

Comment: As a user I'm not sure I'd want a solution based on full terminal emulation.  If your "terminal interactions" are sufficiently limited, maybe you should look into simply adding support for colors (it's a one-liner) and for those terminal interactions to comint (or replacement thereof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to use something like `compilation-shell-minor-mode`.  But I'm not sure how/if it can work in an ansi-term buffer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I had to use. 10 lines of `emacs-lisp` with some regexps solved the issue.